# how to handle kwargs when doing lazily loading in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

i m trying to do lazy loading of python method in flask by using app.add_url_rule
I have url rule created by parsing each python file and getting method_name/argument1/argument2 etc...

But there are kwargs in some method and how do i handle kwargs in my flask endpoint while doing lazy loading, Here is example -

```
def create_user(self, username, userid, **kwargs):
    *Method implementation*
```

url_rule in above case is

```
/create_user/<username>/<userid>
```

if i access http://127.0.0.1:5000/abc/1212/company=new

I get

`Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Any idea how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your `company` variable to be a URL parameter and not a part of the URL itself:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/abc/1212?company=new
```

Then in your app you access them from the `flask.request.args` `dict`:

```
@app.route('/<username>/<userid>')
def create_user(self, username, userid):
    url_params = request.args
    company = url_params.get('company', 'default_if_none')
    ...
```

Comment: I dont want to change anything in existing method, as there are so many method where I am doing lazily loading, is there some way to use kwargs without impacting existing code.